# Converting Array to Object using Reduce

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Can someone explain how this is working.

Learning to use **Array.reduce()**

```
var votes = ['tacos','pizza','pizza','tacos','fries','ice cream','ice cream','pizza'];

var initialValue = {}

var reducer = function(tally, vote) {
  if (!tally[vote]) {
      tally[vote] = 1;
  } else {
      tally[vote] = tally[vote] + 1;
  }
      return tally;
  }

var result = votes.reduce(reducer, initialValue)
```

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions/253896#comment17104_253896

Comment: @JörgWMittag how is this too broad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `Array.prototype.reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array to reduce it to a single value.

In your example the reduced value (the result of a count operation) is assigned as a property of an object called `tally` which is returned by `.reduce()`;

I comment your with a brief explanation:

```js
// your data in an array
var votes = ['tacos','pizza','pizza','tacos','fries','ice cream','ice cream','pizza'];
    // optional value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback when using Array.prototype.reduce(). 
    var initialValue = {}
    // tally = previousValue and vote = currentValue  
    var reducer = function(tally, vote) {
      // if tally is not assign as a key in tally object, add key and add value of one, (basically count 1 for one element in your votes array)
      if (!tally[vote]) {
          tally[vote] = 1;
      } else {
          // otherwise if tally object has already this key, increment its value by one, (basically it counts how many times each item in votes array is present in the array)
          tally[vote] = tally[vote] + 1;
      }
          return tally;
      }
    
    var result = votes.reduce(reducer, initialValue);
    console.log(result);
```

Notes: you can actually avoid using of declaring a variable for `initialValue` and instead using only `var result = votes.reduce(reducer, {});`

API documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Some more examples and brief explanation:

https://www.airpair.com/javascript/javascript-array-reduce

Comment: `if (!tally[vote]) {
          tally[vote] = 1;
      } ` i got confused at this for initial value

Comment: @SiddharthArora basically it says: if value you are considering has not been counted yet, start counting it adding a value of 1. For example when you start to process array `votes` and you found first time `tacos`, this item has not been counted yet, so it will be added to tally object with value 1, the same for second value `pizza`. Instead for the third value `pizza`, value has been already found in object tally, so it will increment its value by 1 (`tally[vote] = tally[vote] + 1;`).... I hope it help :). Let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Really sorry man, I got confused about how to assign value to a property in object. so far i only knew about the .(dot notation).
Thanks @GibboK

Comment: @SiddharthArora You are welcome. Yes in JS you can access property by dot notation of by bracket notation (which is very handy for dynamic lookup). You can read more about Property accessors at the following link. I am gald my answer helped you out with your question. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Answer (score 3):

The way how reduce works is pretty similar to `map` or `filter`. In this case, the reducer is responsible for *reducing* the array of objects into one object.

The reducer function iterates through all elements of your array. The function is called with two arguments, `tally` - *result of reducing so far* and `vote` - *array element that is currently being processed*.

If `tally` does not have a property named just like the element that is currently being processed/reduced, it adds such a key to the object and sets its value to one. Otherwise (key is present), it's incremented by one.

For more information go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 3):

There's plenty of verbose explanations of `reduce` here and other places, but I think a simple visual demonstration might help

```
[1,2,3].reduce(function(a,b) { return a + b }, 0)
// (((0 + 1) + 2) + 3)
// => 6
```

You can see:

- an input list of 3 elements results in 3 computations
- the initial value is used in the computation with the first element
- the result of one computation is used in the next computation …
- … up until the last computation which is the result of `reduce`

---

Now as for your code, we're not building a sum of numbers, we're building up an *Object* that holds the tally count of each string in an array.

There's no point in me explaining what everyone else did, but it's not surprising this might've been confusing for you because no one explained that this is abuse of an Object.

In truth, an Object is actually not the best data structure choice for this reduction. Here, an Object is used to emulate the behaviour of a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

We'll set `initialValue` to a `new Map()` and you'll see how the `reducer` uses more descriptive syntax within. Note comments aren't even necessary because the code says everything it needs to.

```js
var votes = ['tacos','pizza','pizza','tacos','fries','ice cream','ice cream','pizza']

var initialValue = new Map()

var reducer = function (tally, vote) {
  if (tally.has(vote))
    return tally.set(vote, tally.get(vote) + 1)
  else
    return tally.set(vote, 1)
}

var result = votes.reduce(reducer, initialValue)

console.log(Array.from(result.entries()))
```

Output

```
[
  [ "tacos", 2 ],
  [ "pizza", 3 ],
  [ "fries", 1 ],
  [ "ice cream", 2 ]
]
```

---

#### just for funs

I can show you that the visual representation of the sum via reduce is correct/accurate by writing a reducer that builds a string instead of actually adding the numbers

```js
var initialValue = 0
var reducer = function(a,b) { return '(' + a + ' + ' + b + ')' }
var result = [1,2,3].reduce(reducer, initialValue)
console.log(result)
// (((0 + 1) + 2) + 3)
```

This technique might be useful for you when trying to understand/debug your own reducers

Answer (score 1):

I inserted some console.log messages in your code and this helped me understand what was going on.

```js
var votes = ['tacos', 'pizza', 'pizza', 'tacos', 'fries', 'ice cream', 'ice cream', 'pizza'];
    
var initialValue = {}
    
var reducer = function(tally, vote) {
  console.log("tally: ", tally);
  console.log("vote: ", vote);
  console.log("tally[vote]: ", tally[vote]);
  if (!tally[vote]) {
    tally[vote] = 1;
  } else {
    tally[vote] = tally[vote] + 1;
  }
  return tally;
}

var result = votes.reduce(reducer, initialValue)
console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: you can embed code snippets here on SO. No need to host off-site or open your developer console either.

Comment: @naomik: You are right. I edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The **reduce()** method **reduces** the array to a **single value**.

The **reduce()** method **executes** a **provided function** for **each value** of the array (from **left-to-right**).

The **return value** of the function is **stored** in an accumulator (result/total).

You have this **given list**:

```
var votes = ['tacos','pizza','pizza','tacos','fries','ice cream','ice cream','pizza'];
```

Then you make an **Initial List**. *You can modify this and the function will be applied for both lists.*

```
var initialValue = {}
```

"reducer" is initialized as a **function**. *The reason that we place the function in "reducer" is so we can call it more easily further on. You can do whatever you want in this function and it will be executed on the list in the upcoming steps*

```
var reducer = function(tally, vote) {
  if (!tally[vote]) {
      tally[vote] = 1;
  } else {
      tally[vote] = tally[vote] + 1;
  }
      return tally;
  }
```

Finally, the **result** of the function is **stored** into the variable.

```
var result = votes.reduce(reducer, initialValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's try to expand the iteration:

When you execute

```
votes.reduce(reducer, initialValue)
```

It actually does this:

```
reducer(initialValue, votes[0]); // step1, return {'tacos': 1}
reducer(returnedValueOfStep1, votes[1]); // step2, return {'tacos': 1, 'pizza': 1}
reducer(returnedValueOfStep2, votes[2]); // step3, return {'tacos': 1, 'pizza': 2}
reducer(returnedValueOfStep3, votes[3]); // step4 ...
reducer(returnedValueOfStep4, votes[4]); // step5 ...
reducer(returnedValueOfStep5, votes[5]); // step6 ...
reducer(returnedValueOfStep6, votes[6]); // step7 ...
reducer(returnedValueOfStep7, votes[7]); // step8 ...
```

I think it quite clear right now.

And usually, if we do not provide initialValue as the second parameter for reduce, it will take the first element of array as the initialValue, and starts iteration from the second one:

```
reducer(votes[0], votes[1]); // step1 ...
reducer(returnedValueOfStep1, votes[2]); // step2 ...
...
```